# dojo 1.9 Programming Style

Tags: dojo

I am a dojo newbie,when I use dojo ,I am confused by the dojo require block,here I give three way to write dojo,which one is the best?
Programming Style 1,you can see this in dojo tutorial,but I don't like the style,I like add event as html tag attribute like `<div onclick='test()'></div>`,in this style,I can't access function test1()

```
<script>
    require(["dojo/query", "dojo/dom","dojo/domReady!"], function(query, dom){
       function test1(){}
       function test2(){}
       //...other functions
        });
 </script>
```

Programming Style 2,define require once,then use it in funciton

```
<script>
        require(["dojo/dom"]);
        function test1(){
          var dom=require("dojo/dom");
          //do something with dom
        }
        function test2(){
          var dom=require("dojo/dom");   
          //do something with dom

        }
 </script>
```

Programming Style 3,the require block inside the function

```
<script>
        function mytest(){
            require(["dojo/query", "dojo/dom"], function(dom){  
             //do something with dom
            })
        }
        function mytest2(){
            require(["dojo/query", "dojo/dom"], function(dom){  
             //do something with dom
            })
        }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The advised way is to connect your events in the javascript rather than in the dom, like :

```
require(["dojo/on", "dojo/query", "dojo/dom","dojo/domReady!"], function(on, query, dom){
   function test1(){}
   function test2(){}
   on(someNode, on.selector(".myClass", "click"), test1);
});
```

See http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/on.html#selector

If you really want to stick to the declarative way (which is not the preferred dojo way since 1.7), you can put your modules in the global space by adding this to your html :

```
<script type="dojo/require">
    dom : "dojo/dom",
    query : "dojo/query"
</script>
```

See http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/parser.html#declarative-require

Or... you can put your callbacks in the global space by modifying your example 1 to this :

```
<script>
require(["dojo/query", "dojo/dom","dojo/domReady!"], function(query, dom){
   test1 = function(){};
   test2 = function(){};

   //...other functions
    });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For what you are trying to do, I'd go with option 3. 3 is pretty much the same thing as 2, except that it plays nicely with AMD.

I would think that if you had async mode on when doing this:

```
var dom = require("dojo/dom");
```

dom would still be undefined for a brief period of time, leading to a nasty race between the AMD loader and the code that follows.
Chances are as you are doing this:

```
require(["dojo/dom"]);
```

up before you declare your functions you are insuring the the loader finds dojo/dom as fast is possible and likely it will resolve before the code that follows it does, but still you're playing with fire there.